# AADSTS750054: SAMLRequest or SAMLResponse must be present as query string parameters in HTTP request for SAML Redirect binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

Please let me know the code to implement SAML 2.0 implementation in ASP.net MVC with Azure AD SAML2.0.
We have already used the below approuch for SAML Protocol with our SSO but it was not intigrating with Azure AD SAML SSO.

http://www.primaryobjects.com/2013/08/08/using-single-sign-on-with-windows-identity-foundation-in-mvc-net/

Please let me know the issue or let me know how to implement SAML2.0 in ASP.net MVC 5 with Azure AD SSO SAML

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I also faced same problem and it is resolved by opening in chrome incognito mode, hope it will also works for you